# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChainId')

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am calling below method to instantiate a safe :
// here props.account contains signedin owner address

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ethAdapterOwner1 = new Web3Adapter({
          web3,
          signerAddress: props.account
        });


const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapterOwner1,safeAddress});
```

but getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChainId')
    at ContractManager.init (contractManager.js:61:1)
    at Function.create (contractManager.js:45:1)
    at Safe.init (Safe.js:100:1)
    at Function.create (Safe.js:73:1)
    at fetchSafes (Safe.js:61:1)
```

Not sure where i am going wrong as I have initialized ethAdapter properly. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: could you share the full source code? it's important to know what you pass as ethAdapterOwner1

Comment: @mikheevm I have updated the source code.

Comment: What web3 version are you using?

Comment: @mikheevm it got resolved, i had to form the statement like this: const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter:ethAdapterOwner1,safeAddress:item.safeAddress});

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in the way the initialization statement was written.This worked.

```
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter:ethAdapterOwner1,safeAddress:item.safeAddress});
```